# Calculate the angle from camera to detected object

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, haar-classifier

I am currently using haar cascade to detect an object and this returns the x and y pixel coordinates of the object and also the width and height of the object in pixels. (object size is unknown)

I would like to calculate the angle from the camera to the object.

I researched and found out that using just the field of view of the camera and the camera resolution, the angle can be calculated but I am currently not sure how to do this because I could not find anymore information.

I kindly need some help in computing this. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of camera do you use?

Comment: You want the "angle" between which lines? I presume one line is the ray from the camera center to a point on the object, but what is the other line: the optical axis? the vertical to the ground? the image plane?

Comment: @Trilarion i am using a logictech C920 webcam as my camera